# ICollectionView very poor performance while filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, icollectionview

I'm facing with big performance issue while I'm trying to filter ICollectionView.

Collection is populated with about 90000 rows (12 columns).

What I've tried to this very moment:

1. used `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping`
2. enabled `RowVirtualization` and `ColumnVirtualization`
3. used `Dispatcher` (still don't know what for and why)

Here I provide code, that shows what I'm trying to complete:

```
private ICollectionView abcdxView;

public ICollectionView AbcdxView
{
    get
    {
        if (abcdxView == null)
        {
            abcdxView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(context.ut_abcdx.ToList());
        }
        return abcdxView;
    }
    set
    {
        abcdxView = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AbcdxView");
    }
}

private void UpdateAbcdxFilter()
{
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        abcdxView.Filter = w =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IndeksFilter) ? true : StringFilter.Like(((ut_abcdx)w).indeks, IndeksFilter))));
}

private string indeksFilter;

public string IndeksFilter
{
    get { return indeksFilter; }
    set
    {
        indeksFilter = value;
        UpdateAbcdxFilter();
        OnPropertyChanged("IndeksFilter");
    }
}

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AbcdxView,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"  EnableRowVirtualization="True">


public static bool Like(string toSearch, string toFind)
{
    if (toSearch != null)
    {
        Regex findRegex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(toFind).Replace("%", ".*"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return findRegex.IsMatch(toSearch);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I must admit that `StartsWith` method in `UpdateFilter()` works much faster, but it's not what I expect.

I have no more ideas how to manage that. Can you help ?

Comment: Dispatcher is used to run code on the UI thread in order to avoid issues from thread affinity. Startswith will be faster because it doesn't search the entire string.

Comment: Your problem is more likely to be simply so many rows rather than any virtualisation. I wouldn't usually drag 90,000 rows onto a client from a database and then filter them. Filtering on the server is likely to be faster. If you really need that many on the client then build 5 lists with the 90,000 records spread across them. Then filter using a for loop ( not linq ) and multi thread so  you use a parallel foreach. Then append all 5 filtered results into one. Again use for loop rather than linq because it'll be faster. Replace the entire bound observablecollection with your new filtered one.